# Digraph, property of a function

Tags: graph-theory

Let be $ G $ a digraph with nodes $ V(G) $. Consider the function

$\begin{align}&f:\ \mathcal{P}(V(G))\to \mathcal{P}(V(G)),\\[10pt] &A\mapsto \{t\in V(G)\setminus A:\ \forall\ w\in A:\ w-t-\text{dipath does not exist}\} \end{align} $

I want to show this property:
$$ \forall\  X,Y\in \mathcal{P}(V(G)):\ f(X\cup Y)=f(X)\cap f(Y) $$

Proof:

$\begin{align} &v\in f(X\cup Y)\\[10pt]&\Leftrightarrow \quad \text{for all }z\in (X\cup Y): \ z-v-\text{dipath does not exist}\\[10pt]&\Leftrightarrow \quad \text{for all }z\in X: \ z-v-\text{dipath does not exist}\ \land \\& \ \ \qquad \text{for all }p\in Y: \ p-v-\text{dipath does not exist}\\[10pt]&\Leftrightarrow \quad v\in f(X) \ \land \ v\in f(Y) \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad v\in (f(X)\cap f(Y))\end{align} $

Is that correct?